# Изменить кодировку полей в yii\data\ActiveDataProvider

Tags: php, yii2

Нужно сохранять данные в файл в формате csv так, чтобы в виндовском ворде кириллические символы корректно отображались по умолчанию.

Данные я беру из yii\data\ActiveDataProvider.

После некоторых тестов стало ясно, что utf-8 отображается некорректно, а utf-16 - корректно.

Получается, что мне нужно перед сохранением файла все данные, содержащиеся в yii\data\ActiveDataProvider конвертировать в формат utf-16. Функция `iconv($in, $out, $string);` все ясно, но как ее применить ко всем данным, содержащимся в yii\data\ActiveDataProvider?

Или лучше сделать это в модели? Но тогда как сделать так, чтобы данные конвертировались только тогда, когда я им скажу это делать? Просто думал воспользоваться встроенным событием `afterFind()`

Сейчас вариант такой:

1. В модели ко всему найденному результату применяю:

   ```
   public function afterFind()
   {
       parent::afterFind();
       if($this->scenario == self::SCENARIO_CONVERT_TO_UTF16){
           foreach($this->attributes as &$attribut){
               $attribut = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', $attribut);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. В контроллере определяю датаПровайдер так:

   ```
   $searchModelForExport = new ModelSearch();
   $dataProviderForExport = $searchModelForExport->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, Model::SCENARIO_CONVERT_TO_UTF16);
   ```

Не сказать, что что-то изменилось. Как сделать правильно?

Да, использую для экспорта kartik\export\ExportMenu вот с такими настройками. Может быть где-то в настройках просто можно это указать?

```
<?= ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProviderForExport,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
    'fontAwesome' => true,
    'dropdownOptions' => [
        'label' =>  Yii::t('main', 'EXPORT_ALL::Експорт'),
        'class' => 'btn btn-default'
    ],
    ],
    'columnBatchToggleSettings' => [
        'label' => Yii::t('main', 'TOGGLE_ALL::Обрати все'),
    ],
    'target' => ExportMenu::TARGET_SELF,
    'exportConfig' => [
        ExportMenu::FORMAT_TEXT => false,
        ExportMenu::FORMAT_PDF => false,
        ExportMenu::FORMAT_HTML => false,
        ExportMenu::FORMAT_EXCEL => false,
        ExportMenu::FORMAT_CSV => [
            'options' => ['title' => 'Comma Separated Values'],
            'mime' => 'text/csv',
            'extension' => 'csv',
            'writer' => 'CSV',
        ],
        ExportMenu::FORMAT_EXCEL_X => false,
    ],
    'messages' => [
        'allowPopups' => '',
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: csv это вивер там и делай

Comment: @Naumov, если вы думали, что ваша фраза мне поможет, - вы ошиблись. Как сделать во вьюхе это?

Comment: А нужно ли делать. У когото ansci у кого то coi8rus или cp1251 стоит, что тогда ничего. В общем то всё решаеться на стороне ворда устанавливаете разделитель csv и кодировку вот и всё.

Comment: @Naumov Я тоже так сказал, на что мне возразили, что "Было сделано так: открыл и все".

Comment: приведи документацию в аргумент. это не возможно сделать. можно попробывать генерить xls или xml для excel там можно кодировку указать. но не csv

Comment: @Naumov, Я уверен, что это можно сделать. Хотя бы потому, что есть готовый код, который это делает, но как он работает - для меня загадка. Возможно, сами файлы должны быть в кодировке UTF-16 - я не знаю. Если будет необходимость сделать - отпишусь, получилось ли.